# SQL Server Full Text Search NOT Operator

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I want to searh my full text index with NOT operator.

```
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE(MY_TABLE, *, 'NOT name'),
```

The following exception:

```
Msg 7630, Level 15, State 3, Line 1
Syntax error near 'name' in the full-text search condition 'NOT name'.
```

What is the wrong? How can search my full text index with **just** NOT operator?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of not, you can use not contains :

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
where not contains( *, 'name')
```

For reference :

> http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/

Comment: I try the following query:

SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE NOT CONTAINS(*, 'NOT name')

The same exception

Comment: u don't have to put NOT inside the brackets, or else you can follow the approach mentioned in the link in my post

Comment: It's OK but I have a stored procedure taking full text query parameter. SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE (MY_TABLE,*,@QUERY) So, I must use CONTAINSTABLE. Thanks for help.

Comment: You can use a simple CONTAINS within a stored procedure which uses a variable predicate, you're not forced to use CONTAINSTABLE because of that. The only constraint would be the necessity of having rank information, but in your case this would have no sense (I guess that all matching records would have the same rank when you use just a NOT operator - if this was possible).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newcomer to full-text search, but according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) :

> NOT can only occur after AND, as in AND NOT. The OR NOT operator is
> not allowed. NOT **cannot be specified before the first term**.

So in your case, `CONTAINSTABLE(MY_TABLE, *, 'NOT name')` is considered as invalid.
The only way I found to use the `NOT` operator with CONTAINSTABLE is the following :

```
SELECT * 
FROM CONTAINSTABLE({table_name}, *, N'{another_condition} AND NOT name')
```

The syntax submitted by @NG. works fine when you don't need `RANK` information, but as soon as you want it, it appears that you need to add another (dummy) condition before the `NOT` operator (which would be quite messy...don' use dummy conditions if you can avoid it).

**NOTE** : In my opinion, the concept of having just a `NOT` operator within a CONTAINSTABLE doesn't really make sense when your argument is to have ranked results. Indeed, if this was permitted, all matching results would share the same rank value (since they won't contain the excluded tokens). The `RANK` would become an irrelevant information and a simple `CONTAINS` could be used instead `CONTAINSTABLE` (cf. @NG. answer).